# Android how to set a transparent image resource of a view? or Remove the image?

Tags: android, android-imageview

```
((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeart1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
```

I d like to remove my graphicss from my Image Resource so:

```
((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeart1)).setImageResource(null);
```

or something, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you remove image then used

((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeart1)).setImageResource(0);

Answer (score 2):

Use [ImageView.setImageDrawable(null);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) or simply [View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try add transparent png with 1px width and 1px height.