# how to set image as transparent from url android

Tags: android, url, android-imageview, transparent

I am creating the application based on the **weather**. I am using this [FREE API](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx).

Here is my [JSON URL](http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=ahmedabad&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=576099ad5f100306131103).

Now when get the image `weatherIconUrl` from that see here http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png ,I want to make transparent before set it to `imageview`.

I tried Like...

```
 1. android:background="@null"
 2.  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

In short `how to set image as transparent after decode from the url`. please give some ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015280/android-how-to-set-a-transparent-image-resource-of-a-view-or-remove-the-image

Comment: I don't think it is worth to do to "manipulate" a given graphics from web service. Even if possible then you are actually "redrawing" it on Android. Easier way I guess you should have your own graphics. Get the weather code list from the web service. And match it with your local graphics file.

Comment: To achieve this, you need to change the background color of the image to white. Unfortunately I can't explain how, but hopefully this will guide you what to search for.